# Makefile unset variable from all further recipes

Tags: makefile

There are some questions on here that ask about how to unset variables - whether via `unexport` or `undefine`. I'm using GNU make 3.81, so the latter isn't an option, but the former doesn't quite work for me. For example, I want to unset a variable if it came from the environment for the rest of the recipes in this makefile. Here's a sample makefile, I want this to print 0 if `VAR` is set from the environment, but as-is it prints 1:

```
ifdef VAR
ifeq "$(origin VAR)" "environment"
unexport VAR
endif
endif

ifdef VAR
ALIVE := 1
else
ALIVE := 0
endif

all:
    @echo $(ALIVE)
```

How can I make it print 0 in that case? Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unexport` simply tells make not to export that variable to any recipes it runs.  This has nothing whatsoever to do with whether the variable is defined *inside make*, which is what the `ifdef` command tests.

`ifdef` only checks to see if a variable has a non-empty value, though, so you can just use:

```
ifeq "$(origin VAR)" "environment"
VAR =
endif

ifdef VAR
ALIVE := 1
else
ALIVE := 0
endif

all:
        @echo $(ALIVE)
```

to set it to the empty value and get make to print "0" here.